# To make a sprite of one char from string

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

I am just trainning cocos2d-x.
I am trying to make a sprite of one char using CCLabelBMFont.
I wrote the code as follows

```
string str = "I like an apple";
CCLabelBMFont *label = CCLabelBMFont::create(str.c_str() , "font.fnt");
```

How should I write the code to make a sprite of one char from string.

It is a feeling such as follows that I image.

ex)

```
CCSprite *spr = 'I';
CCSprite *spr2 = '\n';
CCSprite *spr3 = 'l';
CCSprite *spr4 = 'i';
CCSprite *spr5 = 'k';
CCSprite *spr6 = 'e';
...
```

Comment: To make it clear: you want to take a string, disassemble it into individual characters and use each one of these characters to create sprite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `string` is an `array` of characters, so any time during run time you can access a single `char` of that string using `str[x]`, where `str` is your string variable and `x` is the index of the char.

For your code you can use a loop :

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < str.size() ; i++)
  // here use str[i] as the char you are looking for
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.Thanks to you,I am able to do it.