# To extract one char from label that are made from CClabelBMFont

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

I am trying to show slowly one char from string ,like novel game.

To do it,at first I wrote the code as follows using CCLabelBMFont to extract one char from string.

```
string str = "I like an apple";

CCLabelBMFont *label = CCLabelBMFont::create(str.c_str(), "font.fnt");

CCSprite *spr = (CCSprite*)label1->getChildByTag(0);
spr->setPosition(ccp(100, 100));

this->addChild(spr);
```

I want to show spr that are extracted from CCLabelBMFont in GameScene(this)

But I am getting the error as follows

```
CCAssert( child->m_pParent == NULL, "child already added. It can't be added again");
```

Why did such the error appear ? and How should I do?

Comment: If I understand you just one to show one char from the Label. Why don't you just use `setString()` and just call it again as you add more characters?

Comment: you can not add same child to parent, you have to create a new one.

Comment: possible duplicate by the same user: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24227438/to-make-a-sprite-of-one-char-from-string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the method you are using and the error you get. You use `getChildByTag(...)` to get your sprite. So what you get is a `child` node of your  `CCLabelBMFont`, meaning it has a `parent`. Your error says that this sprite cannot be added again as a child, because it already has a parent.

I can't think of a straigthforward and sure way to achieve what you want, but here are some suggestions you may try :

- Adding each letter as a seperate label - to be honest, this is really dumb as it unnecessarily multiplies your code and would use too much memory.
- Making the children of your label invisible, and them make them visible one by one. When you create the label, iterate through its children and call `setVisible(false)` on them. Then schedule a call in which you will call `setVisible(true)` on subsequent children.
- Possibly creating subclass of `LabelBMFont` and/or creating a custom action may be the most flexible way, but propably not the easiest.

Let me know if anything is not clear!

Comment: a separate label isn't a very good solution. Why not do basic std::string operations and then `label->setString()` as needed? I'd imagine a loop, tacking on each additional character and then re-setting the text of the label

Comment: That's an excellent suggestion! I must have overthought the whole thing, kudos @GameDeveloper!

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

I understand that I can not add same child to parent.

By the way,though I tryed to use setString() to show slowly one char from string like the following 
site, [http://survive-engineer.hatenablog.com/entry/2014/02/13/013103](http://survive-engineer.hatenablog.com/entry/2014/02/13/013103),

I could not express.

However I used the CCAction and the CCLabelBMFont,somehow I could do.